# Time complexity of a recursive algorithm which split into two per run mostly

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

Dynamic Programming | Set 33 (Find if a string is interleaved of two other strings)

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-a-given-string-is-an-interleaving-of-two-other-given-strings-set-2/

I found a question in this website and it said "The worst case time complexity of recursive solution is O(2^n).". Therefore, I tried to draw a tree diagram about the worst case this question. I assume that when the length and value of a and b are the same, it will lead to a worst case. It will split into 2 parts till the length of a/b is 0 (using substring).

```
                    aa,aa,aaaa
                   /          \
                  /            \ 
           a,aa,aaa             aa,a,aaa
          /        \           /        \
         /          \         /          \
     -,aa,aa     a,a,aa     a,a,aa     aa,-,aa
    /           /    |        |   \           \
   /           /     |        |    \           \
-,a,a       -,a,a  a,-,a   -,a,a  a,-,a      a,-,a
```

In this case, it has 13 nodes which is really a worst case, but how to calculate it step by step? IF the length of c increases by 2, it will got 49 nodes. If it increases to a large number, it will be difficult to draw a tree diagram.

Can someone explain this in details, please?

Comment: Merge Sort : i guess this algorithm is using the same idea(spliting into 2 parts utill one element is remaining) . it just didnt group them back. I will say the complexity would be O(n log n) for worst case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recurrence for the running time is

```
T(n) = 2T(n-1)
```

If you draw the recursion tree you'll see that you have a binary tree with `height = n`.

Since it is a binary tree, it will have `2^n` leaves hence the worst case scenario is `O(2^n)`.